# How to get all words of a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a paragraph in a single string and I'd like to get all the words in that paragraph.

My problem is that I don't want the suffixes words that end with punctuation marks such as (',','.',''','"',';',':','!','?') and /n /t etc.

I also don't want words with 's and 'm such as `world's` where it should only return world.

In the example
`he said. "My dog's bone, toy, are missing!"`

the list should be: `he said my dog bone toy are missing`

Comment: Why would you want to ignore the `'s` in `dog's`?

Comment: Can't you split string on white chars, like spaces, new lines and other? All between two blanks is a word...

Comment: coz im making something that creates a fill in the blanks activity. so if the paragraph contains a name with 's. i think its good to leave 's and only get the name

Comment: What about this one: `Let's go`. So you want: `Let go`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Expanding on [Shan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970538/how-to-get-all-words-of-a-string-in-c/4970625#4970625), I would consider something like this as a starting point:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Match(input, @"\b[\w']*\b");
```

Why include the `'` character? Because this will prevent words like "we're" from being split into *two* words. After capturing it, you can manually strip out the suffix yourself (whereas otherwise, you couldn't recognize that `re` is not a word and ignore it).

So:

```
static string[] GetWords(string input)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[\w']*\b");

    var words = from m in matches.Cast<Match>()
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value)
                select TrimSuffix(m.Value);

    return words.ToArray();
}

static string TrimSuffix(string word)
{
    int apostropheLocation = word.IndexOf('\'');
    if (apostropheLocation != -1)
    {
        word = word.Substring(0, apostropheLocation);
    }

    return word;
}
```

Example input:

```
he said. "My dog's bone, toy, are missing!" What're you doing tonight, by the way?
```

Example output:

```
[he, said, My, dog, bone, toy, are, missing, What, you, doing, tonight, by, the, way]
```

One limitation of this approach is that it will not handle acronyms well; e.g., "Y.M.C.A." would be treated as four words. I think that could also be handled by including `.` as a character to match in a word and then stripping it out if it's a full stop afterwards (i.e., by checking that it's the *only* period in the word as well as the last character).

Comment: If you use `@"\b[w']+\b"` then you shouldn't need to remove the items for which `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. I get back an `IEnumerable<string>` with `from Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"\b[\w'\u2019]+\b") select m.Value` (that one also includes curly apostrophes).

Answer (score 4):

Hope this is helpful for you:

```
        string[] separators = new string[] {",", ".", "!", "\'", " ", "\'s"};
        string text = "My dog's bone, toy, are missing!";

        foreach (string word in text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Regex word boundary expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468102/regex-word-boundary-expressions), [What is the most efficient way to count all of the words in a richtextbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226161/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-count-all-of-the-words-in-a-richtextbox). Moral of the story is that there are many ways to approach the problem, but regular expressions are probably the way to go for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a looping replace method... not fast, but a way to solve it...

```
string result = "string to cut ' stuff. ! out of";

".',!@".ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(a => result = result.Replace(a.ToString(),""));
```

This assumes you want to place it back in the original string, not a new string or a list.

Answer (score -2):

split on whitespace, trim anything that isn't a letter on the resulting strings.